# Indexes are not appearing in Indexing Manager when using Client Certificate Authentication With Solr

Tags: sitecore-client, solr

We have setup Client Certificate Authentication with Solr using below link:
https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2018/08/01/client-certificate-authentication-with-solr/

Solr admin panel is loading without error

Our requirement is when Sitecore request for Solr access, Httpwebrequest has to authorize client certificate to access Solr, so we added patch config as mentioned in above link, we are able to authorize certificate via our pipeline but when we try to access Sitecore Indexing Manager, Indexes are not appearing.
[image]

We did the following Steps:
1. Commented below line of code in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config file.

```
<!--<solrHttpWebRequestFactory type="HttpWebAdapters.HttpWebRequestFactory, SolrNet" />-->
```

2. Added Patch config file - using link: https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2018/08/01/client-certificate-authentication-with-solr/

[image]

3. Updated SSL settings in solr.in.cmd using above link
4. As mentioned in above link: Enabled SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH to true

   set SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=true

   set SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false

When we set SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH to true, Sitecore Indexes stopped appearing on Indexing Manager. The issue is with this setting enabled to true.If I tried to disable this setting to false indexes worked but it is not authorizing properly.

There is some configuration change we need to update to access "Solr SSL Need Client Authentication" in Sitecore which I am not able to find.

We use Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 with SXA 1.7.1

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe dumb question but have you also deployed the code in GC.Foundation.Search.Solr namespace? You are referencing this code from from config but you also need to have dll built and deployed in bin folder

Comment: Also if it's not typo, you are using wrong version of SXA. For Sitecore 9.0.2, you should use SXA 1.7.1. See more info here -> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/180187

Comment: I have already deployed the code in bin folder, when I debug  the code, I am able to get certificate name and its passing through IHttpWebRequest Create(Uri url) method but Indexes are not appearing.  Yes we are using SXA 1.7.1 version its typo.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue with 9.1.  In my case, I restarted IIS and then they appeared.

Comment: Needs to verify the configuration at Sitecore and Solr schema needs to be populated. It means schema files manually needs to be copied in each Solr. After that restart the Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Is Content Search disabled?

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Enabled" value="false" />
```

I've seen some of the Commerce installation processes update the Sitecore.ContentSearch.config file under App_config/Sitecore/ContentSearch folder and set it to "false."

In order to see the indexes in the index manager ContentSearch.Enabled setting must be set to "true"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your reply.

I found the solution. Client certificate with patch code did not work in local. I deployed same patch to Server. It worked.